# Use alternative click or UI element to exclude tags when viewing questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, filtering

If you are viewing a list of questions you can click on a tag and it will filter the questions further by the tag that you've selected.  It would be nice if you could exclude a question with a particular tag in the same way using an alternative click -- double-click, click right mouse button, ctrl-click -- on that tag in the tags list.

**UPDATED:  based on @random's answer.**

Adding the [-] interface element may be a better solution since it exposes the interface in an obvious way.

Answer (score 3):

How about instead of trying to play around with the mouse, something like a little icon next to the tag that would be the exclusion version, the one with the minus?

[**`[tags]`**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) ×95 [[-]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/-tags)
[**`[discussion]`**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) ×83 [[-]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/-discussion)
[**`[questions]`**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questions) ×76 [[-]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/-questions)

Comment: That actually might be better since it exposes the interface.

Comment: Is there any update on this?